# NSMutableURLRequest not honoring User-Agent change

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, webview

I'm trying to make a WebView send a specific User-Agent but for some reason I can't get it to work.

Here is my code :

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.whatismybrowser.com/developers/what-http-headers-is-my-browser-sending"];
    NSString* userAgent = @"Some Cool User Agent";

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setValue:userAgent forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];

    NSLog(@"UA : %@",[request valueForHTTPHeaderField: @"User-Agent"]);

    [self.webView.mainFrame loadRequest:request];
}
```

The output of the NSLog line is `Some Cool User Agent` so it appears this is being set in the `NSMutableURLRequest` object.

My WebView loads the page as expected however the User-Agent reported is : `Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.75.14 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0.3 Safari/537.75.14`

I've confirmed this with [Charles Web Debugging Proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com).

Why is the User-Agent being ignored when the WebView loads the page?

[Complete xcode project here](https://github.com/dwkns/Sling).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
[self.webView setCustomUserAgent:@"Some user agent"];
```